In Drum Machine project, mouse events work properly but Keydown event does not
In my Drum Machine project (React), when switch power is on, I use keyboard to press, there is no sound, however, when I click, it works fine. But sometimes, switch power is off, I use keyboard to press, there is a sound.
Mouseup and mousedown event work properly.
Keydown and keyup events does not.
Here is my code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Pad from './Pad';
import SwitchButton from './SwitchButton';


function App() {
  const [power, setPower] = useState(false);
  
  const handlePowerToggle = (isOn)=>{
    setPower(isOn);
  }
  
  return (
    <div id="drum-machine" className='container'>
      <div className='pad-bank'>
        <Pad id="Heater-1" label="Q" audioSrc='/audio/Heater-1.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Heater-2" label="W" audioSrc='/audio/Heater-2.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Heater-3" label="E" audioSrc='/audio/Heater-3.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Heater-4" label="A" audioSrc='/audio/Heater-4.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Clap" label="S" audioSrc='/audio/Clap.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Open_HH" label="D" audioSrc='/audio/Open_HH.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Kick_n_Hat" label="Z" audioSrc='/audio/Kick_n_Hat.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Kick" label="X" audioSrc='/audio/Kick.mp3' power={power} />
        <Pad id="Closed_HH" label="C" audioSrc='/audio/Closed_HH.mp3' power={power} />
      </div>
      <div className='controls-container'>
        <div className='control'>
          <p>Power</p>
          <SwitchButton id='power' onToggle={handlePowerToggle}/>
          <p id="display"></p>
        </div>
        <div className='volumn-slider'></div>
        <div className='control'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


SwitchButton Component code is here:
const SwitchButton = ({id, onToggle}) => {
    const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(false);

    const toggleSwitch = () => {
        setIsOn(!isOn);
        if (onToggle) {
            onToggle(!isOn);
        }
    };

    return(
        <div id={id} className={`switch ${isOn?'on':'off'}`} onClick={toggleSwitch}>
            <div className="switch-handle"></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SwitchButton;

And Pad Component code is here:
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';


const Pad =({id,label,audioSrc,power}) => {
  //Styling state of Pad
  const [boxShadow, setBoxShadow] = useState('black 3px 3px 5px');
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('grey');
  const [marginTop, setMarginTop] = useState('10px');
  const [height, setHeight] = useState('45px');
  //Ref for audio element
  const audioRef = useRef(null);

  let style = {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    userSelect: 'none',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '100px',
    height: height,
    paddingTop: '30px',
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    marginRight: '10px',
    marginTop: marginTop,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    borderRadius: '10px',
    boxShadow: boxShadow
    }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeyDown);
    //Clean up the event listener on component unmount
    return ()=>{
      window.removeEventListener('keydown',handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('keyup',handleKeyUp);
    //Clean up the event listener on component unmount
    return ()=>{
      window.removeEventListener('keyup',handleKeyUp);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleMouseDown = ()=>{
    console.log('mouse:',power);
    setBoxShadow('none');
    setBackgroundColor('orange');
    setMarginTop('13px');
    setHeight('42px')
    if (power && audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.currentTime = 0;
      audioRef.current.play();
    };
  };

  const handleMouseUp = ()=>{
    setBoxShadow('black 3px 3px 5px');
    setBackgroundColor('grey');
    setMarginTop('10px');
    setHeight('45px');
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event)=>{ 
    if (event.key.toUpperCase() === label.toUpperCase()){
      console.log('key:',power);
      setBoxShadow('none');
      setBackgroundColor('orange');
      setMarginTop('13px');
      setHeight('42px');
      if (power && audioRef.current){
        audioRef.current.currentTime = 0;
        audioRef.current.play();
      }
    }   
  };

  const handleKeyUp = ()=>{
    setBoxShadow('black 3px 3px 5px');
    setBackgroundColor('grey');
    setMarginTop('10px');
    setHeight('45px');
  };

  return (
    <div
      id = {id}
      className='drum-pad'
      // tabIndex={0} //Makes the div focusable and allows key events
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      style={style}
    >
      {label}
      <audio ref={audioRef} className='clip' id={label} src={audioSrc}></audio>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pad

Some styling css:
body {
  background-color: #8d8d8d;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 660px;
  height: 316px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.pad-bank {
  display: flex;
  width: 332px;
  height: 272px;
  margin: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

I tried to inspect the power state in console.log but I don't know how to fix it.
Please help me.
